# Actual text and corrected text? Or autocorrect data?

Tags: nlp, corpora, text

I seek essentially a parallel corpora, which has the dirty original user-generated input on the one side, and a cleaned up version on the other side - with corrected spelling, casing, punctuation and formatting.

So the dirty side should have been composed by human users, and the clean side should have been redacted by human linguists:

> 'how are you', 'How are you?'
>   'is their bad waether?', 'Is there bad
>   weather?'
>   'As of 2011, it was live.', 'As of 2011, it was live.'

Autocorrect data would also be useful.  It would need totals or proportional statistics which imply the relative probabilities:

> 'how', 'How', 0.5
>   'waether', 'weather', 0.7
>   'waether', 'whether, 0.1

(This will then be used to train machines to generate more of the dirty content, given cleanish content, thereby augmenting a text data set.)

Comment: So the set specifically includes entries without corrections (your 3rd line)?

Comment: Either way.  Would be ideal in some sense, but not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this one is a stretch... but instead of comparing text with errors to the corrected text, you can compare original text against incorrect transcriptions.

**[Reuters Transcribed Subset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Reuters+Transcribed+Subset)** and **[data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/reuters_transcribed-mld/reuters_transcribed.html)**

> This data was created by selecting 20 files each from the 10 largest classes in the Reuters-21578 collection. The files were read out by 3 Indian speakers and an Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) system was used to generate the transcripts.

**[Original text - Reuters-21578](http://www.daviddlewis.com/resources/testcollections/reuters21578/)**

You would just have to match the transcribed text with the original.

Comment: Thanks much, I don't think it will work for my intended application, but it's an idea, and could be very useful to others.